# Create dynamic multi-level html menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

I wish to create a menu with two levels. From parent to child to grandchild.

I am unable to change the html because data is dynamic but it always has two levels at some point.

I'm trying to add Child class items wrapped with `<ul></ul>` to `parent` and `grandchild` class items to `child`.

So basically I'm just trying to create a simple menu from dynamic data. I was trying to hard code it in classic asp but i ran into some trouble and I figured it would be a bit easier in JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i, wrap, wrap_number = 0;
    $('li').each(function(){
        var li = $(this);
        if (li.is('.child')) {
            wrap = 'entry_wrap_' + wrap_number;
            li.addClass(wrap);
        } else {
            wrap_number++;
        }
    });
    
    for (i = 0; i <= wrap_number; i++) {
        wrap= 'entry_wrap_' + i;
        $('.' + wrap).wrapAll('<ul/>').removeClass(wrap);
        console.log("i worked+")
    }
        
    // ----
    var i, wrap, wrap_number = 0;
    
    $('li').each(function(){
        var li = $(this);
        if (li.is('.grandchild')) {
            wrap = 'entry_wrap_' + wrap_number;
            li.addClass(wrap);
        } else {
            wrap_number++;
        }
    });
    
    for (i = 0; i <= wrap_number; i++) {
        wrap= 'entry_wrap_' + i;
        $('.' + wrap).wrapAll('<ul/>').removeClass(wrap);
        console.log("i worked+")
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="parent"><b>Menugroup</b></li>
        <li class="child">item1</li>
        <li class="child">item2</li>
        <li class="child">item3group</li>
            <li class="grandchild">item4</li>
            <li class="grandchild">item5</li>
            <li class="grandchild">item6</li>
        <li class="child">item7</li>
        <li class="child">item8</li>
    <li class="parent"><b>Menugroup</b></li>
        <li class="child">item9</li>
        <li class="child">item10</li>
    <li class="parent"><b>Menugroup</b></li>
        <li class="child">item11</li>
</ul>
```

I thought I would just wrap adjacent items, with same class name, with `<ul></ul>`.

**Here is the result:**

```
Menugroup
    item1
    item2
    item3group
    item4
    item5
    item6
    item7
    item8
Menugroup
    item9
    item10
Menugroup
    item11
```

It's close but it's not enough. Because `grandchild` items are separate from `child` items. It's because `li` tags were close before `grandchild` `ul` tags were opened. See what I'm trying to explain [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe3CM.png).

**End goal is a markup like this:**

```
Menugroup
    item1
    item2
    item3group
        item4
        item5
        item6
    item7
    item8
Menugroup
    item9
    item10
Menugroup
    item11
```

I would appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction. I'm mainly searching for solution with js/jquery.

Comment: did you search some jquery plugin for multi-level menu? as I know, there are many sample and plugins. i think it's easier to search them than create from zero. :)

Answer (score 0):

A new generation of children should be wrapped in a `<ul>` tag.
So your HTML should turn out like this:

```
<ul>
    <!-- Parent -->
    <li class="parent"><b>Menugroup</b></li>

    <!-- Children wrapped in <ul> -->
    <ul>
        <!-- Children -->
        <li class="child">item1</li>
        <li class="child">item2</li>
        <li class="child">item3group</li>

        <!-- Grandchildren wrapped in ul -->
        <ul>
            <li class="grandchild">item4</li>
            <li class="grandchild">item5</li>
            <li class="grandchild">item6</li>
        </ul>

        <!-- More Children -->
        <li class="child">item7</li>
        <li class="child">item8</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Parent -->
    <li class="parent"><b>Menugroup</b></li>

    <!-- Children wrapped in <ul> -->
    <ul>
        <li class="child">item9</li>
        <li class="child">item10</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Parent -->
    <li class="parent"><b>Menugroup</b></li>

    <!-- Children wrapped in <ul> -->
    <ul>
        <li class="child">item11</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**Note:** I've only provided an example of what your HTML should turn out to be. I'm not that good at JQuery, however, so I cannot provide the Jquery you should use. I hope my answer provides some help to you.